# How to use draggable (html5 attr) with an iframe page on cross domain

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, draggable

My parent page includes an iframe page on cross domain, and I'm trying to drag an item from parent to iframe using draggable.

However, it can not recognise the "drop" area. And I do the same things with an iframe on same domain, it works!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Sorry I forgot. The codes are shown as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Check my codes as follow:*/
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>localhost:2000/parent.html</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
#iframe{width:100%;height:450px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="item-list" id="items">
    <li draggable="true">1</li>
    <li draggable="true">2</li>
    <li draggable="true">3</li>
    <li draggable="true">4</li>
    <li draggable="true">5</li>
    <li draggable="true">6</li>
</ul>
<iframe src="localhost:3000/iframe.html" id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>iframe</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="trash">Here is trash.</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#trash").on("dragover",function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }).on("drop",function(ev){
        alert("drop!")
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```